# Can I add a temporary cell with dummy data in UITableView?

Tags: ios, ios7, uitableview

Is there any way that I can add a dummy cell with data until the app fetches the real data from the server, then delete it and replace it with real data?

I'm doing this because it takes too long to go and get the data and it is supposed to be a chatroom.

Comment: You can and you should. When you have new data, change the model and call `reloadData`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. For example, if you're using an array to populate your `UITableView`, you can fill that array with the dummy data; then when you receive the real data from the server, you can replace the dummy data at the appropriate indices then call `reloadData` to reload the table and update the cells with the correct data.

Comment: Thank you Lyndsey ,but how to tell the tableview to delete the old data and update them with the new one? as only the last row will be updated

Comment: "reloadData" would reload the entire table; so the tableview wouldn't be deleting the old data, per se, but would be reloading the table using the updated data.