# Can I load dummy cells into an UITableView until I receive data?

Tags: xcode, uitableview, xamarin.ios

We want to smoothen the data loading in our UITableView by adding custom dummy cells until we receive real data. We would like the custom cell to look something like this:

[image: custom dummy cell]

Is it possible to do something like that? We saw similar loading indicators in other apps but have no idea how to implement them.. Maybe someone of you knows if its possible and how?

Comment: why not display a placeholder image and then toggle it's visibility once data becomes available?

Comment: Thank you, yes that would work and I will do that if there is no other way. I was hoping for something thats already built in for loading indicators

Comment: Does my solution work for you? If yes, can you please accept it (click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer ) so that we can help more people with same problem:).

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT Hi, im currently trying to implement your solution to see if it works. Am I supposed to set ShowDummyCell in the ViewDidLoad to true and then in GetData() to false? Or should I really set both of them to false? I think it works if I set it to true in ViewDidLoad, but I cant see any of the cells yet. If it works for me, I will accept your answer :)

Comment: Yes,set ShowDummyCell in the ViewDidLoad to true and then in GetData() to false. When you set to true, you should give some DummyCell and return 1/2/3 lines show those DummyCells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I think you can do that, use a bool value in `dataSource` to check whether to show `DummyCell` or `data cell`. Reload the `tableView` when you `get Data` finished:

Here is a simple example I wrote:

```
public partial class ViewController : UIViewController
{
    UITableView tablview;
    myDataSource dataSource;
    public ViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();
        // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        tablview = new UITableView(this.View.Bounds);

        dataSource= new myDataSource();
        dataSource.showDummyCell = false;

        tablview.DataSource = dataSource;

        this.View.Add(tablview);
    }

    public override void ViewDidAppear(bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewDidAppear(animated);

        getData();
    }

    public void getData()
    {
        dataSource.showDummyCell = false;
        tablview.ReloadData();
    }
}

public class myDataSource : UITableViewDataSource
{
    public bool showDummyCell;

    public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        UITableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell("id",indexPath);

        if (cell == null)
        {
            cell = new UITableViewCell(UITableViewCellStyle.Default,"id");
        }

        if (showDummyCell)
        {
            //...return  DummyCell;
        }
        else
        {
            //...return cell;
        }

        return cell;
    }

    public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableView, nint section)
    {
        if (showDummyCell)
        {
            //...return  DummyCell.count;
        }
        else
        {
            //...return data.count;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Refer: [Can I add a temporary cell with dummy data in UITableView?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23587702/10539446)